# Cryptomatte aliased/jagged edges output

Tags: rendering, cryptomatte

Is there a way to get antialiased output on cryptomatte? 
[image]

Comment: The output of cryptomatte should be as accurate as necessary for the masking. You wouldn't actually use the picker output though, that is just a visual aid for picking the objects you would like to mask. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157043/cryptomatte-what-crypto00-crypto01-crypto02-means/157159#157159) explains how cryptomatte works internally.

Comment: @RobertGützkow what does that mean exactly.. what any other way can i save it ?

Comment: You can save the Cryptomatte in a multi-layer OpenEXR file. The colored output that is shown in the screenshot is from the picker socket of the Cryptomatte node. This is only meant to select which objects you would like to mask, it's not the actual Cryptomatte.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I cant get it to export correctly with EXR...any chance you got a tutorial to point me at ? I watched a bunch but still not being able to do it :S

Comment: I've just seen you new question. The problem is that Photoshop has no support for Cryptomatte, so you would indeed need the colored picker/ID pass to differentiate between the objects. This wasn't clear in the original question.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Is there any way to have all objects in the picked/matte rather than going one by one selecting ( i have tooo many objects...)

Comment: Checkout the answer by brockmann to your newer question, apparently there is a free add-on (or whatever it's called in Photoshop) that gives you Cryptomatte support. That means you don't need to resort to a hacky solution.

Answer (score 1):

The colored image as shown in the question is the output from the picker image of the cryptomatte node. This image is used to quickly pick an object or material from the cryptomatte data. It is not the actual matte.

After picking objects and materials the anti aliased mask will be available from the matte output of the cryptomatte node. This is answered in more detail in [Cryptomatte - Clean edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176671/cryptomatte-clean-edges)